# Qt - Any guideline on how to implement navigation between UI Forms?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm learning Qt right now, trying to make a simple application. What I'm trying to implement is a simple 'Welcome' screen, with two buttons ('Register' and 'Login'). The problem is on the page redirection to the other two pages.

Also, I have the screens already setup using the QtCreator (in .ui Forms format).
The only solution I could come up with, until now, was based on an example from Qt itself, which uses a **QStackedWidget**, adding **QWidget**s as pages. The problem is that those pages in the example are mounted programmatically (and I want to use the Forms that I have).

If I try this:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow() :
        ui_home(new Ui::HomeView),
        ui_register(new Ui::RegisterView) {
    ui_home->setupUi(this);
    ui_register->setupUi(this);

    pagesWidget = new QStackedWidget;
    pagesWidget->addWidget(ui_home->centralWidget);
    pagesWidget->addWidget(ui_register->centralWidget);
    ...
}
```

It 'kind of works', but the result is horrible. The 'centralWidget' from my Forms is added to the 'pagesWidget', but the 'setupUi' before that really renders the 'Home' and 'Register' pages all at once, messing everything up.

So, real question is:

> Is there any guideline on how to implement navigation between UI Forms?

Secondly:

> How can I retrieve the QWidget from my UI Form and add to a QStackedWidget, without rendering it?

I am using Ubuntu 12.04, with QtCreator 3.2.1.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do it wrong. You should create a "MainWidget" with 2 items: a) `QStackedWidget`, b) navigation panel (your buttons). Then you should set "MainWidget" as a central widget.

After it you can connect signals from navigation panel (clicked signals of "Registed" or "Login" buttons) to corresponding slots, that will select necessary widget on `QStackedWidget`

So, in your case, you need next 3 ui forms:

1. MainWindow (QStackWidget + 2 buttons)
2. LoginWidget
3. RegisterWidget

Pseudocode:

```
// RegisterWidget.cpp + you should have RegisterWidget.ui
RegisterWidget::RegisterWidget()
  : public QWidget(NULL)
  , ui( new Ui::RegisterWidget() )
{}

// LoginWidget.cpp + you should have LoginWidget.ui
LoginWidget::LoginWidget()
  : public QWidget(NULL)
  , ui( new Ui::LoginWidget() )
{}

// MainWindow.cpp + you should have MainWindow.ui
MainWindow::MainWindow()
  : public QMainWindow()
  , ui( new Ui::MainWindow() )
{
  ui->setupUi(this);
// !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
// Creating widgets here.
// Possible - setup communication between widgets with signals / slots
// !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
  m_loginForm = new LoginWidget();
  m_regForm = new RegisterWidget();
  ui->stackedWidget->addWidget( m_loginForm  );
  ui->stackedWidget->addWidget( m_regForm );

  connect( ui->loginBtn, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::onLogin );
  connect( ui->regBtn, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::onReg );
}

// private slots:
void MainWindow::onLogin()
{
  ui->stackedWidget->setCurrentWidget( m_loginForm );
}

void MainWindow::onReg()
{
  ui->stackedWidget->setCurrentWidget( m_regForm );
}
```

And don't forget about layouts. Because you may see nothing if your widgets will have 1x1px size.

> How can I retrieve the QWidget from my UI Form and add to a QStackedWidget, without rendering it?

You may use `QWidget::hide()` method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Right. But how could I connect an .ui Form with a 'LoginWidget' class that way?

Comment: What you mean by "connect an .ui Form with a Widget"? You need to have 3 forms. Each form should implement it's own logic.

Comment: Yes, that's the objective. But I what couldn't figure out yet, how to 'connect' a "ui_login.ui' (the XML file containing the screen structure) with a class "LoginWidget".

Comment: If you add an .ui file to a project - then Qt Creator will generate necessary .h and .cpp files for you. "Connection" in you case will be done in `setupUi` method. It is autogenerated by moc.  All mmagic is there, so you may open ui_LoginWidget.h file and check a code.