# Where do i change the label on clicking a button QT

Tags: forms, qt, user-interface, navigation

i made a GUI for a project, it has multiple forms and i don't know how to connect them.....the thing is that the navigation between these forms is not linear.

The user's choice on the first page (radiobuttons) decides what the next form will be, i developed a basic algorithm using if statements, but i don't know the navigation action.

here's the if statement

```
 void InputChoice::on_commandLinkButton_clicked()
{
if (ui->radioButton->isChecked()){
     //Go to state vector input;
}
if (ui->radioButton_2->isChecked()){
   //Go to orbital element input
 }

if (ui->radioButton_3->isChecked()){
   //Go to TLE input
 }
```

So i want to know

1-  the syntax and/or the principal that we use to link the forms together. 
2-  How can i put it in a conditional statement.
3- i read in some place that it would be a good option to use the command link button

Thanks alot :))

Comment: i'm looking for the syntax of the statement written in gray comment below each if statement

Comment: I hope [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26162336/qt-any-guideline-on-how-to-implement-navigation-between-ui-forms) may help you.

Comment: If you're creating a wizard-like interface, have you considered using the QWizard framework?

Answer (score 0):

```
    void InputChoice::on_commandLinkButton_clicked() {

    if (ui->radioButton->isChecked()){

     //Go to state vector input;
    vectorInput = new VectorInput(); // show the form
    vectorInput->exec(); // Don't let anything else happen until choice is made on form

    //or you could also just use show(); but the user can do other things while    form is showing
    vectorInput = new VectorInput();// show the form
    vectorInput->show();

    }
    else if (ui->radioButton_2->isChecked()){
    //Go to orbital element input
    //Same as above
    }

    else if (ui->radioButton_3->isChecked()){
    //Go to TLE input`enter code here`
    //same as above
   }

    else{
          //Do something.
        }


   //Should be something like this. If not, can you elaborate a little more             or where can I see the code?
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your help :)) i found a wway to make it through making the forms "dialog" instead of "widget".

But how are you dealing with the forms as vectors, does the QT know on its own that vectorInput is the form?? i mean, we didn't declare anything up there. 

thanks again :))

Comment: You should have created a private member in your .h file. Like VectorInput *vectorInput; I'm assuming this is some type of form because you are calling it a form.